# Substring apply automatically on text type column in query

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have following query

```
select * from table1
```

if table1 contains text type column/columns then I need only 100 characters

Assume, End User don't know the schema(columns name) of table,Just know table name
Executing this query from query analyzer that is front end application.
User writer query in textarea and executes

*I am Using SqlServer2005
Dont use substring function in query from frond end
I can use substring function on text columns in C# code but I want this in database end.
*

Comment: You can create a view of the table that does the substring and then you give your users access to the view only.

Comment: I don't want to create views.There are more then hundred tables in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to specify a table name, and get in return the result of SELECT * FROM  with all the text fields limited to 100 characters, and all that on the database side?

Seems to me you need to create a stored procedure to do that. Your input parameter would be the table name, then you'll go on querying the table's structure, and build a dynamic SELECT statement that uses the SQL substring on text fields larger than 100 characters. Run the dynamic SQL statement inside your stored procedure, and that will be your result.

To get the table structure, just run the stored procedure [`sp_help`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with the table name as a parameter. The result will contain the column names and types. Loop over it to build your dynamic SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this in application logic rather than in SQL, especially since it seems that you are talking about more than one table.

Use The `SqlDataReader`, loop through the results and cut the strings as you need them:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
  var rawValues = reader.GetValues();
  var values = new object[rawValues.Length];

  for (i=0; i < rawValues.Length; i++)
  {
    var value = rawValues[i];
    if(value != null && value is string && value.Length > 100]
      values[i] = value.SubString(0, 100);
  }

  //now do whatever you want with the values
}
```

To avoid constant reflection (`is string`) you could also use the schema info of the reader to figure out which are string columns.

Comment: My Database and web server are in different region.

Comment: meaning you want to save bandwidth or it's simply to slow?